# Jenkins to Linux Issues - Python File execution

Tags: python, linux, jenkins

I am quite new to linux set up and I am finding it really tough to make my jenkins machine talk to a python program residing in a linux server.
Here are the details:

- I have a python file which resides in a path '/filenet/EFBI/Scripts/Test_Scripts/add.py'
- I have created one Jenkins Job to run the add.py file which has the JenkinsHome path set in the same linux machine -'/jenkins/jenkins_fmlvlm0000/jenkins2_176/Jenkins_Home'
- I donot have access to the workspace file inside the Jenkins_Home (using a user to login to the linux box).

In the Jenkins Job configuration I have written the below code:

```
#! /usr/local/bin python3
python3 /filenet/EFBI/Scripts/Test_Scripts/add.py
```

When this gets executed receiving a error:

```
started by user Jenkins Admin User
Running as System
Building in workspace /jenkins/jenkins_fmlvlm0000/jenkins2_176/Jenkins_Home/Workspace/PythonTest
[PythonTest] $ /usr/local/bin python3 /jenkins/jenkins_fmlvlm0000/jenkins2_176/apache-tomcat-9.0.20/temp/jenkins123456789.sh
FATAL : command execution failed
java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission Denied
....
....
....
....
caused: java.io.IOException: cannot run program "/usr/local/bin" (in directory "/jenkins/jenkins_fmlvlm0000/jenkins2_176/Jenkins_Home/Workspace/PythonTest"): error=13, Permission Denied
```

Now I have below questions:

1. Where am I going wrong?
2. How to find out which user is being used to interact between jenkins and linux python program?
3. Is this a permission issue and what all permission be required?

Comment: Check which user has rights to run the Jenkins jobs that means this user must have rights to execute the python program. Also, you can try to give your python executables present in /usr/local/bin executable by giving 755 permission. Give the same permission 755 to add.py

Comment: Don't know anything about jenkins, but are you sure there should be a space here `#! /usr/local/bin python3` between bin and python, and not `/` because it seems it's trying to run "bin"

Comment: James Z - If I do this way it will give me Name Error : Python3 is not defined

Comment: thanks for your input @souravatta But I didnt understan your point of giving 755 permission, which file should have 755 permission in /usr/local/bin . I will check if the jenkins job can be provided access into the python paths

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved now. 
We had to create a slave node and then in the linux machine create a worker folder for the agent to work.

And then in the set up create the same user ID and password through which we are logging into to linux machine and then provide required SSH permission to make it work.